# SQL DB Model For Sales

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to cerate DB Model for Below Scenario

1. user can purchase product and can pay fully, partially or later.
2. user has facility to pay money anytime in a financial year
3. Interest will be calculated for the money user paid and for money user owes,  user has to be paid based on difference , if not it will be carry forward to next financial year.
   user can settle account at the end of financial year or in the middle of financial year. have to track these settlements as well.

we have to track users transaction history (kind of ledger).

Appreciate your suggestions!!

Comment: yes. I agree, its not a free service. am doing some POC and stuck  without having knowledge how to proceed. So, thought of asking here. If you are willing to help, you can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends how products are being sold, but I can give my opinion.

You need to have a Products table (obviously), a Purchase table (for each purchase of products, you should have here the user who purchased and the price the product was at the time of purchasing) and a Purchase-to-Product table (to elaborate what was purchased).

Then you can add to your Transactions table a foreign key to Purchases (so for each purchase you'd be able to sum how much was paid)

And I suggest to add a payment status column in the Purchase table, to know if it was paid fully, partly, or for late (and you can update it each time you add a transaction)